# How to insert display equations in a Word document without breaking a paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting, equations

Is there a way to write a display equation in Word 2013, without starting a new paragraph?

For example, the following text is a single paragraph:

[image]

Notice how after the display equation, there's no identation, indicating that the whole thing is a single paragraph. How do I do this in Word? Is there a way to insert display equations in word without breaking a paragraph?

Comment: Are you sure that the text following the equation is not a new paragraph without indentation?

Comment: @Sekhemty It's an image. It could be anything. I just need the simplest way to achieve this effect in Word.

Comment: @Karan It is a good question and I tried to answer it. That's precisely what I am saying. It's a snapshot from a book and I want to reproduce this effect in Word.

Comment: Even if the line beginning with ***P(r)*** is a new paragraph, can't you simply delete the first line indent, if any? Any reason why it must be an unbroken paragraph?

Comment: @Karan I would have to delete the first line indent every time I want to insert a display equation inside a paragraph. Isn't there a more consistent way of doing this? Besides, it is also annoying that Word wants me to capitalize the first letter of the line after the equation. It's constantly inviting me to make a mistake.

Comment: Well I don't even use a first line indent normally so not a big deal for me. I'll see if it's possible and get back to you if I find anything.

Comment: I think that your best option is to remove the indentation after the equations. I can't understand how it could be a single paragraph, given that these text blocks have different formatting like alignment, margins, spacing and of course indentation. I.E., how could you align to the center the equation without putting it in its own paragraph with a different formatting from the alleged parent paragraph? Maybe in HTML it could be done with a CSS, by specifying that every paragraph after an equation should have no indentation, but I don't know hot to do that in Word, except by doing manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually very simple: just use "line breaks" (which can be input by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) instead of "paragraph marks/pilcrows" (which are input by <kbd>Enter</kbd> itself). Word will treat the equations after a "line break" or "pilcrow" as a Display equation by default. Thus, you just need to

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after "the interaction is",
2. Click "Insert an Equation"
3. Type your equation
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
5. Continue your text input.

And Word will not treat the text before and after the equation as two sentences or two paragraphs. The final result is like this (I added a "where" before P(r) to show that the words before and after the equation belong to the same sentence, otherwise my Word 2013 will complain that the "w" is not upper-cased):

[image: no new sentence/paragraph screenshot]

I turn on the option to display the paragraph marks (pilcrows, line breaks,...) to make my points clearer. For more information about these marks, see an old link [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/formatting/NonPrintChars.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the problem with Word automatically capitalizing the first word of a sentence, go to Word Options and go to the proofing section.  Click on Autocorrect Options at the top, go to the Autocorrect tab and uncheck the "Capitalize the first letter of sentences".

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac (Word 2011), there is an option to change the display to Block (see screenshot below). There should be something similar in the Windows version.

[image: sample from my version of word]

[sample word doc with inline & block equations](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/422123/sample-inline---block-equation-using-the-same-block-of-text-docx.html)

Comment: I don't see a "block" setting. Can you produce a Word document with a "block" equation, and upload it somewhere so I can see what it looks like from Windows?

Comment: wait... do you mean "Inline"? An Inline equation is on the same line as the text. That's not what I am looking for. I need a Display equation (that is, an equation in its own line), that doesn't break a paragraph.

Comment: see the link i added to the bottom of my original response. it has both inline and block styles for the equation (it's what i took the screen shot from).

Comment: I see it. Too bad on Windows there's no block option! I wonder why that is?

Comment: Can you try something? Try justified text and tell me what happens. Here in Windows, the last line before the display equation (that says "interaction is") is stretched through the page width... very ugly!

Comment: yes, that happens on mac too. it's because the last line doesn't have a line terminator so word thinks it needs to justify the line.

Comment: @becko, If you replace the line break after "interaction is" with a paragraph break instead the output is what you expect even with justification alignment. However note this is only working because the equation is treated as the first line, this may suffice for you depending on your situation.

Comment: @Adam The problem with doing that, is that what comes after the equation is treated as a different paragraph, and Word complains that it isn't capitalized, and if there's indentation, it will be idented. That's not what I want (see the question).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a "hack" that **partially** solves the issue. Before the equation, there should be a paragraph break, as before, but after the equation, use a line break instead. If there's identation, you'll see that the line after the equation won't be idented, and justification will work as usual. The problem with this is that Word still wants you to capitalize the first character of the line after the equation. I don't know how to solve that yet.

Since this is a partial solution only, I am not marking it as the answer.

Comment: Isn't just my suggestion from my other comment?

Comment: @Adam, as I understood it, you suggested using paragraph breaks both before and after the equation. What I am doing is putting a paragraph break before the equation, and a line break after the equation. I did get the idea from your comment... If it's the same as what you had in mind, then the credit is all yours ;)

Comment: My bad for the ambiguity, when I played with the sample document associated with this question there was already a line break after the equation. No worries, I thought I was seeing double for a second is all :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Word 2010, but I think it should work in 2013 as well. It's simpler than you think. Type the paragraph with the equation initially inline, not putting in any paragraph breaks. Then select the equation and hit Change to Display.

[image: Inline]

Becomes

[image: Display]

Comment: Try doing that using Justified text. The last line before the equation will be stretched and it looks very ugly.

Comment: This was justified, but because there was only one word on the last line, I didn't see your issue. I thought there was an option to change the justification settings, but I couldn't find it. After you change it to Display, put your cursor right after the last word on the top section and then hit Enter and then Delete.

Comment: That's equivalent to what I said in my answer above. You'll end up with a paragraph break before the equation and a line break after.

Comment: Mine doesn't have the issue with capitalizing the second paragraph, but okay. You should mark an answer then.

Comment: As I said, it's equivalent to my answer. Here, Word keeps giving me the squigly lines because of capitalization in the line after the equation. Note that in the figure you post, the first line after the equation begins with an equation... try putting some text there and you'll see.